# How to do a nearby search of multiple locations in a single request to google places api

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I want to get multiple specific locations using the google places api nearby search.  What is the format for querying multiple locations with the NAME parameter.  The api shows the following for a single location:

```
     https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere
```

I read in the documentation that you can specify multiple types by appending a | .

How do I specify multiple name parameters in a google place api nearby search?

Comment: as per documentation you should use **space**, but its not working. but **keyword with space saprated** works for me.

Comment: hi, any update for the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use multiple types for search use can bitwise OR operator. See the last line of append where I have used 3 different types.
Here is an example

```
private String getUrl(){

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
    if(mLastLocation != null){
        sb.append("location=" + mLastLocation.getLatitude() + "," + mLastLocation.getLongitude());
    }
    sb.append("&radius=" + searchWithin);
    sb.append("&sensor=true");
    sb.append("&key=" + getString(R.string.map_api_key));
    sb.append("&types=" + "restaurant|atm|bank");

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to specify the different names in the "name" field of your request variable. Separate them with | and surrounded with quotes.

```
var request = {
  location: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8665433,151.1956316),
  radius: '500',
  name: "name1|name2|name3",
  types: ['store']
};

service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests